# Facebook Connect: Reloading web page after login

Tags: javascript, facebook

On http://www.stubwire.com/account/login.php I am trying to add the Facebook Connect, and once they login it reloads the page. I have tried searching and I see other posts, but unable to figure out why my page is not working. Can someone help me figure out why this is not working?

```
<script>
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
      appId      : '139440482805508',
      status     : true, 
      cookie     : true,
      xfbml      : true
    });
    FB.Event.subscribe('auth.login', function(response) {
      window.location.reload();
    });
    FB.Event.subscribe('auth.statusChange', function(response) {
      window.location.reload();
    });
    FB.Event.subscribe('auth.authResponseChange', function(response) {
      window.location.reload();
    });
  };
  (function(d){
     var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk'; if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
     js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
     js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
     d.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(js);
   }(document));
</script>
```